# How to select the datasource of a child Kendo grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to do jump into a next row using jquery in kendo. My children grids are generated automatically and my question is how to select it dinamically. Otherwise, I use something like this:

```js
      $('#childGridName').on('keydown', 'input', function (event) {
        if (event.which == 13) {
          event.preventDefault();

          var index = $(this).closest('tr').next().index() +1;

          for (var i = index; i < $('tr', '#childGridName').length; i++) {

            var data = $('#childGridName').data('kendoGrid').dataItem($('tr', '#childGridName').eq(i));

            if (data != undefined) {
                $('#childGridName').data('kendoGrid').editCell($('tr', '#childGridName').eq(i).find('td:eq(2)'));
                return;
              
            }  
          }
        }
      });
```

Comment: So you want to navigate between the *cells* and, when navigating the cells should be enable for editing. Is that right ?

Comment: yeah, I want to go to next editable cell that is under this one where we are now, on enter pressed

Comment: Check if this helps http://dojo.telerik.com/AFetu

Comment: it doesn't work unfortunately for dinamically generated child grid :/ i cannot have fixed grid name in my definition

Comment: But you can change that to find the generated grid. The code I proposed can be fully dynamic..

Comment: but it was my question, how to do it dinamically, my code from my question works as your works when we have static grid, can you help me do it dinamically?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94921/discussion-between-aviator-and-dontvotemedown).